# How to print the index of a map?

Tags: c++

I have a loop

```
for (itr=addr->second.begin(); itr!=addr->second.end(); itr++)
```

if I have 10 entries in the map and If I want to print out the index Im in (like 1,2,3,4..10), is there any way to print it out with out using another variable. Thanks.

Comment: What map? `std::map`?

Comment: `std::distance(addr->second.begin(), itr)` maybe?

Comment: @remyabel: That's pointlessly inefficient if the container doesn't have random access.

Comment: Is the collection ordered? std::distance will be O(1) on random access collections but will require traversing the undrlying data structure otherwise, which would be quite inefficient.

Comment: Is `addr` your `std::map`, or is `addr->second` your `std::map`?  You haven't shown enough information to make a clear answer with the current state of your question.

Comment: Because maps are ordered and have random access, it should be O(1), correct?

Comment: @remyabel No, wrong. Maps are ordered and have no random access. Access is `O(log n)`.

Comment: @H2C03 OK, I was just reading that anyway.

Comment: Also, why don't you use another variable?

Comment: Just curious if map has any internal function to print the index of the entry.

Comment: @user2333234 No, it hasn't, as at least two users here informed you of the fact. Also, documentation.

Comment: Boost's `flat_map` supports random-access iterators.

Comment: The easiest way that is fairly efficient with a std::map will be to use an additional counting variable for the index and increment each time through the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* print the index of the position you are at but it is hideously inefficient: the items in a `std::map<...>` don't have an index. You can determine the index as the distance from the start, though:

```
for (itr=addr->second.begin(); itr!=addr->second.end(); ++itr) {
    std::cout << (std::distance(addr->second.begin(), itr) + 1) << ','; // not recommended!
}
```

That is, yes, it is possible but it is certainly not something I would do! I don't recall ever having had the need to have an index for an object in a `std::map<...>`. If I had to get the values of a `std::map<...>` in combination with an index, I would just use another variable or a custom iterator which tracks the map's iterator and a counter.